# Watch two variables and only trigger if both have been changed ? VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to watch two variables (or more) and trigger a method only if both variables change. So far, I have only figured out how to watch multiple elements and trigger a function when one element changes.

is there any solution ?

Comment: have 2 single watchers and have a check inside each to see if the other value has also changed

Comment: Why don't you check if the two variables are set in the function that should be called from the two watchers?

Comment: the variables are in the store, and the watcher and the method are in a mixin.

@depperm how do you check in a watcher if the other value changed ?

Comment: @MajedBadawi I need to check if the variabled have been changed and not to check if they are set

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
      computed: {
        twoVariables: {
          return [this.var1, this.var2]
        }
      },
      watch: {
        twoVariables(newValue, oldValue) {
          if (newValue[0] !== oldValue[0] && newValue[1] !== oldValue[1]) {
            //do stuff
          }
        }
      }
```